# Apache hive error Merging of credentials not supported in this version of hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hbase, java-io

I am using hadoop 1.2.1, hbase 0.94.14 and hive 1.0.0. There are three datanodes in my clsuter and three regionservers also. I have to import some data from hbase to hive. I have configured hive successfully but when I ran a command to count no. of rows in hive table, its gives following

```
ERROR [main]: exec.Task (SessionState.java:printError(833)) - Job Submission failed with exception 'java.lang.RuntimeException(java.io.IOException: Merging of credentials not supported in this version of hadoop)'
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Merging of credentials not supported in this version of hadoop
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.configureJobConf(HBaseStorageHandler.java:485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PlanUtils.configureJobConf(PlanUtils.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork.configureJobConf(MapWork.java:540)
```

I have changed version of hive to 0.14 but same error.
What is the solution of it?
Note: I cannot upgrade hadoop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your version of Hive is current, this is not the source of your error. You need to upgrade your Hadoop version, to 2.4.0 or above.

The error originates from here https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/3b6825b5b61e943e8e41743f5cbf6d640e0ebdf5/shims/0.20S/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/shims/Hadoop20SShims.java#L579

Comment: In question, it is mentioned that I cannot update hadoop version

Comment: Because Nutch does not support other versions

Comment: In that case can you show more of your code, so we can suggest alternative approaches.

Comment: I have to create a table in hbase that is managed by hive. For that I have followed a guide given https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration

Comment: Is there any alternate way to create a table in hbase managed by hive ?

Comment: According to http://nutch.apache.org/ you cannot use other than hbase 0.94.x for latest version of Nutch. And according to http://hbase.apache.org/apache_hbase_reference_guide.pdf for hbase 0.94, hadoop supported version is 1.x . What is the solution ?

Comment: @Shafiq: Why are you trying to use Hive-HBase integration? As per my experience, hive-hbase is very primitive. 
Do you need capability to do sql like queries on HBase? Have you looked at http://phoenix.apache.org/. Phoenix is built just for hbase.

Comment: @AnilGupta this question is not from me

Comment: @mattinbits: oops sorry. fixed my comment.